# Using Alias in AppleScript-ObjC in Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode8, applescript-objc

I am attempting to use Xcode and AppleScript-objC to zip a folder containing some network test files but get an error on this section of code.

```
set homeFolder to (path to home folder)
set homeDesktop to (POSIX file (POSIX path of homeFolder & "/Desktop/NetworkTestResults/"))

tell application "Finder"
    set theItem to homeDesktop as alias
    set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
    set fileName to name of theItem
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
    set zipFile to quoted form of (theFolder & fileName & ".zip")
    do shell script "zip -jr " & zipFile & " " & itemPath
end tell
```

The error text is "Can't make <> into type alias. (error -1700)

Any thoughts on how to correct/work around this?

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Error did not format correctly, should say "script" in the middle of <<>>

Comment: Script works for me as long as NetworkTestResults exists. Please show the header of your the file and try to log output (--> homedesktop). In addition you can shorten your code as (path to desktop) will directly give you the path of the current users desktop.

Comment: The script has always worked in AppleScript. my issue is I get the error when putting this script into Xcode. It does not want to use the Alias keyword.

Comment: Maybe its coercing as homeDesktop is recognized as script. Try add 'as text' at the end of your 2. line.

Comment: ... and in addition - is it an applescript xcode application? or swift/objective c with applescript implemented?

Comment: It is an AppleScript Xcode application. tried modifying to:set homeDesktop to (POSIX file (POSIX path of homeFolder & "/Desktop/NetworkTestResults/")) as text

Comment: Still getting the the same error.

Comment: I decided to cut the code here and use a shell script to zip the file using terminal. That resolved the issue.